# Why is $w^2$ a complex root for the equation $x^2+x+1=0$?

Tags: complex-numbers

"Multiplying both sides by $(x-1)$ gives $x^3-1=0$ which is the 3rd roots of unity. Its complex roots are also denoted as $w$ and $w^2$."

Comment: Please write precisely what you are asking for.

Comment: You can just use the quadratic formula on the original equation.  Are you asking why we call this $w$?  Often it is $\omega$.  It is just a number that comes up somewhat frequently, so we give it a name.

Comment: You have to understand what's $w$. Suppose $w$ is a cubic root of the unity, so in particular $|w|=1$. Then, multiplying by $\overline{w}$, in the equation $w^3=1$ you get $w^2=\overline{w}$. And you know that non-real roots of polynomials with real coefficients are there by conjugate pairs. In this way $w^2$ must be a root since it's the conjugate of a root. You can use a different reasoning to prove every power of a root of unity is a root of unity, too.

Answer (score 1):

Let $w$ be a complex root of $x^2+x+1$.  Then $w^2+w+1=0$ so $w^3-1 = (w^2+w+1)(w-1) = 0$, so $w^3=1$, so $w^4=w$.  Therefore $w^4+w^2+1=w+w^2+1=w^2+w+1=0$, so $w^2$ is also a root of $x^2+x+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty obvious after you examime the geometric sum;
$$x^2+x+1=\frac{x^3-1}{x-1}$$
In general
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} x^j=\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$$